# PHP DB connection code returning empty connection variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to my database but its returning an empty connection.

When i do var_dump($conn) its showing as empty.

Any advise on how to debug why its empty?

Thanks.

```
$dbhost = "localhost:3306";
$dbuser = "abc";
$dbpass = "efg";
$dbname = "hij";

$weightToUpdate =0;
$account="";
$email="";
$hawb="";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$myfile = file_put_contents('dhlemail.txt', "Conn is 
".var_dump($conn).PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$myfile = file_put_contents('dhlemail.txt', "Conn is 
".var_dump($conn).PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

To:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

And this will give you the answer why can't you connect to your db.

**P.S -** change `$dbhost = "localhost:3306";` to `$dbhost = "localhost";`
You don't need to include your port.

Comment: Its not showing an error but its also not showing any records from database. When i run the query manually on the server i am getting 1 record but here i am getting empty when i dump the variable.

    $sql = "select weight,account,hawb from consignment where awb='".$awb."'";

    $myfile = file_put_contents('dhlemail.txt', "about to query database".$sql.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
    $myfile = file_put_contents('dhlemail.txt', "result of query".var_dump($result->fetch_array()).PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);